# Json Request working only my computer (VB.Net desktop app. Project)

Tags: json, vb.net, restsharp, rest

I have a json request in my vb.net desktop app project (.net framework 4.5.2). This codes working every time correcctly in my computerand i saw response json string every time.

But i tried run in other machines, not worked. Response is every time nothing in other machines. Any ideas on the reason for this?

```
Dim wcOrders As List(Of Woocomerce.Root)

Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function() True
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Dim client = New RestClient("https://[??myhost??].com.tr/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?context=view") 

client.Timeout = -1

Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.[GET])
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic [MyAuth.Info]")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)

wcOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Woocomerce.Root))(response.Content)

If IsNothing(wcOrders) Then

  MsgBox("not")

ElseIf wcOrders.Count = 0 Then

  MsgBox("0")
  MsgBox(response.Content)

Else

  MsgBox(wcOrders.Count)

End If
```

Comment: What does *Response is every time nothing* mean?

Comment: You can get RestSharp to deserialize for you, by the way

Comment: When i worked this codes in my computer, i saw json string (woocommerce order lists) every time. And I serialized this json to object. But same codes not working other machines.

Comment: Does woocommerce have some sort of whitelist IP or other firewall that would allow your computer to connect to the API but not others?

Comment: Also, can you verify .Net Framework 4.5.2 is installed on those other computers?  A simple google should tell you how to find that (think you have to check in the registry).

Comment: I tried different machine in my office. It's ip is same with my machine.

Comment: Yes, .Net Framework 4.5.2 is installed on those other computers.

Comment: I tried 3 different machine. first machine in my office (windows 2007) and same ip address with me. second and third machines has different ip adresses and installed windows 2016 server.

Comment: Might be worth looking at using the wooCommerce .net library.  Does all the hard work for you.  https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of Exception message it is? If it does not work on another computer, there is no reference file, or there is no vanity on the server side, or it is a security program on the PC, check the firewall.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'm logging all exceptions but i haven't any exception messages. Yesterday, i tried all logging to all response messages and i saw create ErrorMessage and ErrorException for response in another machines. 
ErrorMessage: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." 
I used this codes for security protocol:
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
After i tried Tls, Tls11 and SSL protocols. But i saw this exception every time.
This problem happens on other machines.